# How do I modify devise so that Pins are read only on Rails 4.2.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am a junior developer building my first web application for a customer using Rails 4.2.4, Devise for authentication and Pins scaffolding for the listing of the customers products for sale.

Everything is working, users can signup and login and then create, read, update and destroy pins.

Problem is, I don't want users to be able to create, update or destroy the pins on my index.html.erb page. (only view such as this is customer sales products)

If you look at the image attached. When you click on the ladies products BTN on the Home page it takes you to the index.html.erb where the pins are listed.

NB: I still want users to be able to signup and log in through DEVISE, but only to update their address details for shipping and not change the pins content. The pins CRUD content should only be created by the customer.

How should I approach this.

[image]

Comment: Just to confirm `Pin` is the name of your model?

Comment: also seems you have different type of users like customer and other users ? am i right ?

Comment: .. _but_ what is pin ?

Comment: @RichPeck I have two models - user.rb and pin.rb PLEASE see my models here with the active user association https://www.dropbox.com/s/6xnjgwyf743pyou/MODELS.pdf?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I approach this

You're looking at [authorization](https://serverfault.com/questions/57077/what-is-the-difference-between-authentication-and-authorization)...

- **Authentication** is the process of verifying who you are (login).
- **Authorization** is the process of verifying that you have access to something (permission).

--

**Devise** is authentication (user is logged in), authorization is a different matter.

Ryan Bates (RailsCasts) made a [very good video & tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan?view=asciicast) about it - he made a gem called [`CanCanCan`](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) which is now the bulwark of Rails authorization; [`Pundit`](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) is another.

What you're asking is how to give **permission** to users who are of a certain type to perform certain actions. The answer is to use either `CanCanCan` or `Pundit` to evaluate whether the user will have the credentials to CRUD a `Pin`:

```
#Gemfile 
gem "cancancan"

#app/models/ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user) #-> looks for "current_user" from devise
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.customer?
      can :manage, Pin
    else
      cannot :manage, Pin
    end
  end
end

#app/controllers/pins_controller.rb
class PinsController < ApplicationController
   load_and_authorize_resource
end
```

The above will only allow users who are set as `customer` to manage the `Pin`. Since you've been scant with model / controller code, the above the most specific I can be about it.

Comment: Nice clean definitions, sir. +1

Comment: Thanks Arup, means a lot!

Comment: Essentially I have over developed the login to the extent that users who are signed in can create, update and destroy the pins which are listed in a jQuery masonry fashion.(but I can't have that LOL as that is the customers listed products on pins) I want users to be able to login but not have authority to do so, only view the content. Is it the case that I need to have an admin built for the customer to list his products and curtail the functionality available to the user upon sign in

Comment: Hey Rich, really appreciate your time. I have put a link to my models above.

Comment: You've not done any over developing - everything is good. I'm just saying the functionality you want to implement is called authorization. It goes on top of what you're doing currently

Comment: Hey Rich, the code you were kind enough to list above. Where would that go in my project. And given the info pertaining to my 2 models. pin.rb and user.rb What do I do to these two models in terms of changes. https://www.dropbox.com/s/6xnjgwyf743pyou/MODELS.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Dude you're the junior developer. This is earning your crust, I can't do your work for you.